# How to program routes to a model DB without a view in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, model-view-controller

I have a website that translates DNA codons to MRNA codons. I created am immutable immutable 64 row DB model with 3 columns with sqlite, which I then preceeded to seed. Basically, what I want is the user to input a string into a text-area and break the string into 3 character string fragments "ttcttaatt..." --> (dnaCodon) [ttc][tta][att] --> that match to the database returning matched results (mrnaCodon ) [uuc] [uua] [auu]. I created a search form on one of my static pages

I am running into trouble now with my routes in the search form. I want to query the search and then return it either to the same page, or a different page- whichever method is easier and makes more sense. I initially created my DB without scaffolding because I don't want it accessible by users for alterations. I ended up creating a scaffolding folder so I dunno why it's not connecting to the database. My page refreshes but does not return the DB query

app/controllers/aa_data_bases_controller.rb

```
class AaDataBases < ApplicationController
   def index
      @aa_data_bases = AaDataBases.new
   end

   def create
  if params[:search]
      @aa_data_bases = AaDataBases.search(params[:search]).order("created_at       DESC")
  else
      @aa_data_bases = AaDataBases.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

end

views/static_pages/sequence.html.erb
It's in this static page that the problem route is, in form_tag("/sequence"...
When I run rails server the pages loads, i can input but page refreshes and nothing happens

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sequence') %>
<h1>Sequence</h1>

<body>
    <div class="content-container-1" id="div3">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-center">
            <h3>Add your sequence here</h3>

          </div>

           <div class="row text-center pt mb">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <br>

              <%= form_tag("/sequence", :method => "AaDataBases#index", id: "search-form") do %>
              <%= text_area_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Translate DNA codons...", 
                  :size =>"75x10", class: "form-control"%>

              <% @aa_data_bases.each do |match| %>
              <li><%= match.mrnaCodon %></li>
              <% end %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'

  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'

  match '/seqresults', to: 'static_pages#seqresults', via: 'get'

  match '/sequence', to: 'sequence_page#sequence', via: 'get'

  get 'aa_data_bases/index'

  get 'aa_data_bases/create'
end
```

model/aa_data_bases.rb

```
class AaDataBases < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.search(query)
    where("%#{query}%") 
  end
end
```

DB

```
class CreateAaDataBases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :aa_data_bases do |t|
      t.string :aaFullName
      t.string :dnaCodon
      t.string :mrnaCodon

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My seeding file, there are 64 entries just like this

```
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "phenylalanine", dnaCodon:"ttt", mrnaCodon:"uuu")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "phenylalanine", dnaCodon:"ttc", mrnaCodon:"uuc")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"tta", mrnaCodon:"uua")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ttg", mrnaCodon:"uug")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ctt", mrnaCodon:"cuu")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ctc", mrnaCodon:"cuc")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"cta", mrnaCodon:"cua")
```

Controller for static pages
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

  def seqresults
  end

end
```

app/controllers/sequence_page_controller.rb

```
class SequencePageController < ApplicationController
    def sequence
    end
 end
```

Comment: The `/sequence` method routes to `sequence` action of `static_pages` controller. However, you've shared the code for `aa_data_bases_controller `. Please share the code for static_pages controller.

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani added the static_pages controller

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here:

1. The Form in your sequence view posts to the sequence URL with a GET, which has an empty action.  So it just renders the sequence view.  This is the behavior you're seeing, and it is what you should expect based on how this is all written.
2. I don't see any view here that would actually render the contents of @aa_data_bases.  What view have you built that will consume this controller variable and display the resulting set of codons?  Does such a view exist already?  If not, you will need to create one.

Some quick suggestions:

1. Your results are not static, so I'd move the sequence page out of the static pages controller.  You are probably going to want an integrated search/results page, so your users can easily do sequences of searches.  Start by shifting '/sequence' to the AaDataBases#index method.  Add a basic index method that sets the value of @aa_data_bases to an empty array.  Optionally you can configure it to handle a `search` query parameter.
2. Move your current index method on the AaDataBasesController to a create method, so it can respond to POST requests
3. Change the sequence view you've created to display a result set based on @aa_data_bases if it isn't empty, and update the form to use POST.
4. Make sure your routes include both the `index` and `create` routes.

These changes should get you to a functional set of pages.

Comment: made some edits, however some of the things you suggested  went over my head. Could you provide further guidance please?

Comment: please help? added changes